How to add a two-digit number to stack
I am currently writing a code that inputs a function as a string from the user, coverts it to a postfix expression, then converts it to infix, then evaluates the expression.
It is a work in progress but I am facing a problem in the process. The program only works if the number is a one digit integer.
It will give me an error if the coefficient is 50 or 1.4 for example.
I tried a couple of things but its giving me an error every time.
I tried to make split every integer on its own and then regroup them:

#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


typedef struct token{
  int type;
  int value;
  double value1;
  int trig;
  int precedance;
  struct token *next;
} token;

typedef struct {
    double items[200];
    int top;
    //double top1;
    struct Stack *previous;
} Stack;

void printStack(Stack *s) {
    printf("Stack: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <=  s->top; i++) {
        if(isdigit(s->items[i])){
            printf("%d ", s->items[i]);
        }else{
        printf("%c ", s->items[i]);
    }}
    printf("\n");
}


double evaluate_postfix(Stack *postfix, double* x) {
    Stack eval_stack;
    initialize(&eval_stack);
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= postfix->top; i++) {
        char token = postfix->items[i];

        if (isdigit(token)) {
            
            j = 1;
            double tmp = token - '0';
            while (isdigit(postfix->items[i + j])) {
                tmp = tmp * 10 + (postfix->items[i +j] - '0');
                j++;
            }
            i = i + j -1;
            push(&eval_stack, tmp); // Convert char to int
            
..}

void infix_to_postfix_and_evaluate() {
    Stack infixtmp, infix;
    initialize(&infixtmp);
    initialize(&infix);
    token *tmp = head;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        switch (tmp->type) {
            case T_NUMBER:
                push(&infix, tmp->value1 + '0'); // Convert int to char
                break;
                
      ...}


void define_type() {
    
int j = 0;  // Start j from 0 to handle the initial digit within the loop
if (isdigit(Function[i])) {
    nexttoken->type = T_NUMBER;
    nexttoken->value1 = Function[i] - '0';
    
    
    
}
    



I also tried grouping them first, but that also dosnt work...
void define_type(){
int j = 1;
if (isdigit(Function[i])) {
    nexttoken->type = T_NUMBER;
    nexttoken->value = Function[i] - '0';
    while(isdigit(Function[i + j])) {
       nexttoken->value = nexttoken->value * 10 + (Function[i + j] - '0');
       j++;
    }
    i = i+j-1;


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: you posted quite a lot of code. Posting a [mre] will help us help you.

You should convert all numerical strings to their internal type before you put them on the stack. That would allow for more than a single digit, and also handle float rtypes. Use the atoi, atof etc. functions of the C library to help you.

I'm not sure why you're putting chars in an array of doubles.
If I iterate over an array of chars like:
void DoParse(char *pszFormula, unsigned nLength)
{
    float fNum = -1;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
    {
        if ((fNum >= 0) && !isdigit(pszFormula[i]))
        {
            printf("Fnum: %f\n", fNum);
            fNum = -1;
        }

        switch(pszFormula[i])
        {
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                printf("Found operator %c\n", pszFormula[i]);
                break;
            default:
                if (isdigit(pszFormula[i]))
                {
                    fNum = (fNum >= 0 ? fNum * 10 : 0) + (pszFormula[i] - '0');
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    if (fNum >= 0)
    {
        printf("Last fNum: %f\n",fNum);
    }
}

The input 103+34*26 gives me:
Fnum: 103.000000
Found operator +
Fnum: 34.000000
Found operator *
Last fNum: 26.000000

The input 43-64/6 gives me:
Fnum: 43.000000
Found operator -
Fnum: 64.000000
Found operator /
Last fNum: 6.000000

If I want to support non-integer parameters, I need to atof like OldBoy suggested.
void DoParse(char *pszFormula, unsigned nLength)
{
    char szNum[12];

    memset(szNum, 0, sizeof(szNum));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
    {
        switch(pszFormula[i])
        {
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                if (*szNum && !isdigit(pszFormula[i]))
                {
                    float f = atof(szNum);
                    printf("Found a number: %f\n", f);
                    /* purge buffer */
                    memset(szNum, 0, sizeof(szNum));
                }

                printf("Found operator %c\n", pszFormula[i]);
                break;
            case '.': /* append point to num buffer */
                szNum[strlen(szNum)] = pszFormula[i];
                break;
            default:
                if (isdigit(pszFormula[i]))
                { /* append digit to num buffer */
                    szNum[strlen(szNum)] = pszFormula[i];
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    if (*szNum)
    {
        float f = atof(szNum);
        printf("Found last number: %f\n", f);
    }
}

Input like 94.3+43.4/42 now gives:
Found a number: 94.300003
Found operator +
Found a number: 43.400002
Found operator /
Found last number: 42.000000

You could also try using strtok or sscanf.
The best suggestion for debugging your define_type method is to make it take an input parameter, rather than using a global variable. That way, you can test a wider variety of strings quickly. Start with a simple integer parameter, followed by a decimal-fraction, followed by progressively more complex expressions.
